# Why heappop time complexity is O(logn) (not O(n)) in python?

Tags: python, heap

For a list, the heappop will pop out the front element. Remove an element from the front of a list has time complexity O(n).
Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 13):

A *heappop()* rearranges `log(n)` elements in the list so that it doesn't have to shift every element.

This is easy to see:

```
>>> from random import randrange
>>> from heapq import heapify, heappop
>>> h = [randrange(1000) for i in range(15)]
>>> heapify(h)
>>> h
[80, 126, 248, 336, 335, 413, 595, 405, 470, 592, 540, 566, 484, 970, 963]
>>> heappop(h)
80
>>> h
[126, 335, 248, 336, 540, 413, 595, 405, 470, 592, 963, 566, 484, 970]
>>> #       ^----^---------^----^----^----^----^---------^----^----^--- elements that didn't move
```

Note that the popping operation didn't move most of the elements (for example 248 is in the same position before and after the heappop).

Answer (score 6):

The documentation is somewhat misleading if you're thinking about what `list.pop` does.

If `heap` is a minheap, then `heap[0]` is indeed the smallest item. Python's `list.pop` method returns the *last* element of the list, but `heapq.heappop` returns the *smallest* (first!) element of the heap. However, it does this by popping off the last element of the heap (which is an O(1) operation on a list), swapping it with `heap[0]`, bubbling it up (this is O(log n)), and then returning the value removed from `heap[0]` to the caller.

So: `list.pop` returns the last item from a list and is `O(1)`. `heapq.heappop` returns the first item to you, but not by shifting the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

Heap pop is indeed `O(logn)` complexity.

What you are missing is that pop from a heap is **not** like "removing the first element and left shift all elements by one". There is an algorithm to move element inside the list, after popping, there is no guarantee that the remaining elements in the list are in the same order as before.

Comment: Yes.  That is the clearest explanation of what is going on.  A *heappop()* rearranges log(n) elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the implementation of heapq.heappop: https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/heapq.py

It doesn't remove an element from the front of the list, it just returns it and replaces it with something else which takes O(logn), and reduces the length of the underlying list by removing the last element.

Comment: Heap pop is never constant time.

Comment: @liliscent, correct, my sentence is perhaps poorly worded, what I mean is that "removing the last element from the underlying list is constant time". I'll edit.